# RSPEC failed with email formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have been browsing the Rails tutorial with putting together the user account and running tests on it for the project I am working on.

```
Failures:

  1) when email format is invalid should be invalid
     Failure/Error: @user.email = invalid_address
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user.email = valid_address
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:81:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.527 seconds
9 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:67 # when email format is invalid should be invalid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:78 # when email format is valid should be valid
```

I have no clue what the problem is. I see what it says, but I even C&P the code from the tutorial to double check what I did to ensure everything was type properly.

Here's the user_spec file.

https://gist.github.com/pwz2k/4770845

Here's the user.rb file.

https://gist.github.com/pwz2k/4770854

The fails did not appear until I added the email validation.

Comment: The nil:NilClass error is telling you that @user doesn't exist / isn't set to anything. Which tutorial are you using?

Comment: partially following michael hartl tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial. I had to follow it to create user register/profile part for my website.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're creating @user before you start testing it.. do you have these lines in your User test? ([rails tutorial listing 6.16](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-email_format_validation_tests))

```
before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
end
```

Comment: Yes.

 `before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") `

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear!. You're setting email to nil class. Which means you're supposed to set the email to a user which we say

```
 @user.email = "something"
```

The error is complaining there is no user, and there won't be any email for user.

To make is work here is an example code  which will help you to fix this issue.

```
 describe "validations" do
   before(:each) do
     @user = User.new(name: "gates", email: "somename@gmail.com")
   end
   it "should be invalid" do
     invalid_emails = %w{gs@gmail p.com name.gmail.com foo.ymail}
     invalid_emails.each do |invalid_email|
       @user.email = invalid_email
       expect(@user.email).to_not be_valid
    end
   end

   it "should be valid" do
    @user.name = "somename"
    valid_emails = %w{user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp 
    a+b@baz.cn}
    valid_emails.each do |valid_email|
     @user.email = valid_email
     expect(@user.email).to be_valid
    end
   end  
 end
```

Please be make sure you've created a fixure for user in your fixures folder.

Hope this helps!